# I can't retrieve data from a JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a website in wordpress and I'm using wordpress json API to retrieve data for a web-app I'm developing. The json API is working fine: 
http://danielvivancos.com/edu/wordpress/?json=1
I get my Json file. 
But now I'm trying to print it in my html page with getjson jquery method. First I'm just just trying to display in a div some information from the json file to check that it is working but i don't know why it's not.
Here you can check my script:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$("#btn382").click(function(){       

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $.getJSON("http://danielvivancos.com/edu/wordpress/?json=1&count=1", function(data){
        var html = [];


        $.each(data.posts.author, function(index, author){           
            html.push("id : ", author.id, ", ",
                      "slug : ", author.slug, ", ",
                      "name : ", author.name, "<br>");
        });


        $("#div381").html(html.join('')).css("background-color", "orange");
    }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ /* assign handler */
        /* alert(jqXHR.responseText) */
        alert("error occurred!");
    });
});
});
```

And of course I have the #div381 created.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I'm really stuck.
Any help would be appreciated!!

**EDIT**: The console error is: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

**SOLVED**: I've changed the coma for a plus sign and changed the way of iterating through the file just as is explained below in one of the the answers.

Comment: Is your script on danielvivancos.com domain or domain use CORS? if not then you need to use JSONP.

Comment: Use `console.log(jqXHR);` instead, with a JS console open of course.

Comment: a '{' is missin behind function(data) ?

Comment: **Always** check the JS console, it would have output a `SyntaxError` in your case.

Comment: Yes. My script is on danielvivancos.com.

Comment: what's the name of the script?

Comment: it has no name. it's placed in my index.html

Comment: and what's the full url? Because at http://danielvivancos.com/, it's not there

Comment: The URL is http://danielvivancos.com/edu/directebre_app_jquerymobile/. If you click on JSON button you'll see it displays no data from the JSON file. I dont't know why. Please I need help!

Answer (score 1):

It seems the type of the `posts` is an array and the first element is a hash which contains `author`.

Try to rewrite

```
$.each(data.posts[0].author, ...
```

**UPDATE**

```
html.push("status : ", data.status, ", ",
   "count : ", data.count, ", ",
   "pages : ", data.pages, "<br>"); 
$.each(data.posts, function(index, post){
   html.push("id : ", post.author.id, ", ",
     "slug : ", post.author.slug, ", ",
     "name : ", post.author.name, "<br>");
});
```

Comment: I've t ried what you say and the console error dissapears but my data isn't shown. I've simplified my code and I've written: $.each(data, function(index, post){           
                html.push("status : ", post.status, ", ",
                          "count : ", post.count, ", ",
                          "pages : ", post.pages, "<br>");            please check in this page http://danielvivancos.com/edu/directebre_app_jquerymobile/ and press the button JSON. I can't understand why it displays nothing...thanks in advanced!

Comment: I think you are confused at all. `data` is a Hash. `each` on data iterates key-value pairs and produces (index=status, post="ok"), (index=count, post=1), etc. Just move your block in `each` outside of `each` to print the values. To access to the `author` key you must iterate  on each of `data.post` array items and get `author` key of an item. I have apdated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `posts` property in your JSON File is an `array`.

So you need to loop through that array first, to access the `author` property!

```
$.each(data.posts, function(i, post) {
    var author = post.author;
});
```